# Deriving convexity from Taylor series expansion

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Why is the function $f(x) = \sum^\infty_{k=1} (3x)^{2k}$ convex? What is the condition on the coefficients to deduce that $f$ convex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you require that $f(x)$ represents a convergent series for it to be defined at a real number $x$. This gives $f$ its domain: $D = \{x: |3x| < 1\}=\left(-\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$, then you can differentiate term-by-term since the series that represent $f$ is now absolutely convergent. Thus $f''(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^{2k}(2k)(2k-1)(x^{2})^{k-1}\geq 0, \forall x \in D, \forall k \geq 1$, and hence $f$ is convex for all $x \in D$.

Comment: We can simplify this, once the domain is established, simply by noting that $(3x)^{2k}$ is convex for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$; and even infinite sums of convex functions are convex, when the sum is finite.

Answer (score 0):

This approach could be off-topic; so, forgive me if this is that case. $$f(x) = \sum^\infty_{k=1} (3x)^{2k}=\sum^\infty_{k=1} (9x^2)^{k}=\frac{9 x^2}{1-9 x^2}$$ in the domain KfSsOc's answer clarified.

So, in the domain, $$f''(x)=\frac{18 \left(27 x^2+1\right)}{\left(1-9 x^2\right)^3}>0$$